# How to create road lines using HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have created a road using canvas. There I wish to add lines in the middle. Also width, height and gap between lines must be increase accordingly.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="500"></canvas>

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var j = 0;
    for(var i = canvas.height*.30; i< canvas.height; i=i+20){
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(canvas.width*.50, i-j, 3+j, 10+(j*2));
        context.fillStyle = '#000000';
        context.fill();
        j++;
    }
```

But I couldn't make it by above code. Please help me to solve this.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcdLf0xu/)

Comment: Help you with what? The maths of it? You know how to draw on a canvas the rest of it is fairly basic maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** : the following solution considers the skew in each line as well so it does not draw rectangles, instead polygons are used.
fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/tcdLf0xu/4/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
var j = 0;
var y = 0;
    for(var j = 1; y < canvas.height; j++){

        context.beginPath();
        spacing = 2.5
        w = j+1;
        h = 4*w;
        x = canvas.width*.50 - w/2;
        y = y + spacing*h;  
        context.rect(x,y ,w,h );
        context.moveTo(x,y);
        context.lineTo(x+w,y);
        context.lineTo(x+w+1/spacing,y+h);
        context.lineTo(x-1/spacing,y+h);
        context.lineTo(x,y);
        context.closePath();
        context.fillStyle = '#000000';
        context.fill(); 

    }
```

Note that its important that you understand what each variable is doing in order to improve the design.

- j is incremented linearly, is just a counter till your height is reached by y.
- w, the width is increased linearly with each iteration of j.
- h, the height is always 5 times the width (change that factor if you want)
- x, the position is offset by half the width from the center.
- y, would be a multiple of the height to accomodate white space efficiently, i took it as 2.5 but can adjust.

Comment: I don't think he need's to be concerned about the skew, he can transform the whole canvas element from perspective to get that effect naturally.

Comment: @mystrdat, only if the road is the only drawing on the canvas